# How to receive data to HTML page from TCP/IP server using socket connection and Server-Sent Events in real-time?

Tags: c#, sockets, signalr, server-sent-events

I am trying to receive data in real-time from tcp/ip server using socket and  Server-Sent Events.

Here is some code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
    Response.ContentType = "text/event-stream";

    try
    {
        clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        //Server is listening on port 1000
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 1000);

        //Connect to the server
        clientSocket.BeginConnect(ipEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SGSclient", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Response.Write(string.Format("data: {0}\n\n", i));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Response.Flush();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But Callback method is not working. Could you please me explain about Server-Sent Events and SingalR to receive data from TCP/IP in real-time?

Comment: What is SingleR? Do you mean SignalR?

Comment: Yes it is. Corrected. I checked it working nice for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft ASP.NET **SignalR** is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies the process of adding real-time web functionality to your applications

**SingalR** is working perfect. I found good response time for my needs.